# Setting random state for cross_val_score doesn't work

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am attempting to run a 3x 10-fold cross validation. Problem is I keep getting the same results from the three different iterations which tells me that the folds are not splitting differently. Why is that and how can I make this to be random each time (or at least based on i)

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import statistics as stats
import random
import numpy as np

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
                           n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                           random_state=0, shuffle=False)
print(X)
print(y)


CVScores = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    np.random.seed(i)
    ada = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=np.random.RandomState(i))
    ada.fit(X, y)
    CVScores.extend(list(cross_val_score(ada, X, y, cv=10, scoring="f1")))
print(CVScores)
mean = stats.mean(CVScores)
print(mean)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function thatsolves this.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold
import statistics as stats
import random
import numpy as np

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
                           n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                           random_state=0, shuffle=False)
print(X)
print(y)


CVScores = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    kf = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
    kf.get_n_splits(X)
    ada = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=100)
    ada.fit(X, y)
    CVScores.extend(list(cross_val_score(ada, X, y, cv=kf, scoring="f1")))
print(CVScores)
mean = stats.mean(CVScores)
print(mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined random_state in your function. A defined random_state is "random enough", but strictly deterministic in order to produce reproducible experiments. Please refer to the [wiki-page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-random-state) on random states, and perhaps dig into the bigger theory of [random seeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed).

> random_state : int, RandomState instance or None (default) Determines
>   random number generation for dataset creation. Pass an int for
>   **reproducible output across multiple function calls**. See Glossary.

In order to avoid this, either don't set it at all, as the default is `None`, or set it as none: `random_state=None`

Comment: Thank you replying to this. I tried passing an int as well (```ada = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=i)```) but I still get the same output from the three times that the crossvalidation is called.